# Stanford CPP lib compilation failure

Tags: c++, qt-creator, visual-studio-2017, mingw32

I am trying to use the [Stanford CPP library](https://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/). Everything was working perfectly well, and I managed to import the library's functions into my projects. And then suddenly, without notice and without me doing anything I can remember, it started throwing various errors whenever I try to compile any file. For example:

```
've' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
```

and
    'm_observers' was not declared in this scope

My file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main{return 0;}
```

I tried #including files from the Stanford library, and I tried removing both of the topmost statements, to no avail.

Now, the errors themselves are not important, because the libraries were definitely working for me in the past, so the problem must not be with the libraries but with my configuration.

I tried this both with Qt Creator 5.9.1 (with MinGW 32bit) and Visual Studio 2017, on a Windows 10 64 bit.
Note: this problem started happening just after Qt Creator published a downloadable snapshot of version 5.10, so might this be related?

Comment: Can you show the specific compiler error you're getting and the line at which that error is occurring? (I work with these libraries a lot.)

Comment: Last time I got an error like this I had accidentally inserted a space in a line that had `std::vector` in it.

Comment: Running Windows Runtime device detection.
No winrtrunner.exe found.
Cannot read C:/Users/Omer ASUS/Documents/build-hello-world-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/.qmake.cache: No such file or directory
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'g++'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
Error while parsing file C:\Users\Omer ASUS\Documents\CS106B\Programming assignments\simple-project\simple-project.pro. Giving up.
Cannot read C:/Users/Omer ASUS/Documents/CS106B/Programming assignments/build-simple-project-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/.qmake.cache: No such file or directory

Comment: Lines which trigger errors: 
Every line with 'std::ve' or 'm_observers' in it, for example:
observable.h line 60: std::ve<Observer*> m_observers;
lexicon.cpp line 199: std::ve<std::string> result;
observable.cpp line 20: m_observers.insert(obs);

Comment: It sounds like you accidentally deleted the string `ctor` from every instance of `std::vector`. Maybe this was a search-and-replace gone wrong? I'd recommend getting a clean copy of the libraries from the Stanford website.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks.